# Amplify redirects not working for fonts in Next.js app

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I am following these [Amplify Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa) from AWS to setup redirects for my Next.js app

But when I add the redirects for the SPA, the website gives me a 404, the same redirect is working fine on another React app, but fails for the Next app.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[image: Redirect SS]

Edited: Change after @Brian suggestion
[image: Change after @Brian suggestion]

Answer (score 0):

Amplify Redirects work from top to bottom. Your first line `/<*>` matches everything and you set the result to `404`.

If you remove the first line and only keep the SPA redirect one, it will work.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa

Comment: Did it but still same result
In my other React app, amplify itself adds the /<*> above the regex rewrite, but it works there. I updated the question with an ss after applying your suggestion, still same problem.